# Convert 2D input array into a non balanced BST

Tags: java

I have an input which is a 2D String array. This has to be converted to a BST. 
Input in the form of parent-child pairs

```
1 3
2 3
10 2
```

How can this be implemented? This is my code:

```
public class Solution {
      public class TreeNode {
      public int value;
      public List children = new LinkedList();

      public TreeNode(int rootValue) {
        value = rootValue;
      }

    }
  static int createTree(String[][] dataset) {
    //return -1;
    int numOfRows = dataset[0].length;
    // Create the child to parent hash map
    Map parentChildMap = new HashMap(numOfRows+1);
    for(int i=0; i<=numOfRows;i++){
      parentChildMap.put(dataset[i][1], dataset[i][0]);
    }

    Collection children = parentChildMap.keySet();

    Collection values = parentChildMap.values();

    Collection clonedValues = new HashSet();
    for (Integer value : values) {
      clonedValues.add(value);
    }

    clonedValues.removeAll(children);

    if (clonedValues.size() != 1) {
      throw new Exception("More than one root found or no roots found");
    }

    int rootValue = clonedValues.iterator().next();
    TreeNode root = new TreeNode(rootValue);

    HashMap valueNodeMap = new HashMap();
    valueNodeMap.put(root.value, root);

    // Populate all children into valueNode map
    for (Integer child : children) {
      TreeNode valueNode = new TreeNode(child);
      valueNodeMap.put(child, valueNode);
    }

    for (Integer child : children) {
      TreeNode childNode = valueNodeMap.get(child);
      int parent = parentChildMap.get(child);
      TreeNode parentNode = valueNodeMap.get(parent);
      parentNode.children.add(childNode);
    }

  }

}
```

But I am unable to get a non-balanced BST to have to searched through.
Is using a hashmap a way to go about it?

Comment: Do you need the BST to be balanced or not?

Comment: Non balanced BST